# Will an AJAX-based website stop JavaScript from being re-evaluated on each page load?

Tags: ajax

I'm making a web app, and I thought about using AJAX to make the website faster. Will using AJAX to update the container-div in practice lead to a faster website? Because of cache, loading will have no impact, but will it go faster because the JavaScript doesn't have to be re-evaluated on each page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AJAX for everything, there is no page load, so yes, JS only is evaluated once.

Also less data is transferred overall so things should be quicker.

However, make sure each page still has an URL that can be visited to get that content without JS so that Google et al. will still be able to index the site (if that's important!)

Comment: So it will really be faster? Why doesn't other websites do it like this then? I have seen many websites, but not many that does it this way!

Comment: Lots do it like that (Google, Facebook, Twitter). Many websites use a # or a #! in the middle of the URL - they are using AJAX like this.

Comment: So you think it's a better way of doing it? It's a layer that is optional. My website is just like a "normal" website, it only has a JS-file that is included which unbinds the regular links and binds a function that does the AJAX. So it adds a GET-var ajax=1 to indicate to PHP that Twig should inherit from an AJAX-template rather than the full HTML-snapshot template. Do you think it's worth it? Writing a JS-loader and a few workarounds to get this working? It's probably 120 lines of JS-code uncompiled. Is it worth it in the end? I haven't made any website with other professional people...

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. Personally, I generally don't do sites like this, but I do do web apps in this style. Mainly because in most web apps each view/whatever doesn't need to be indexed by Search Engines so it's less of a concern.

Comment: Hmm, so you are saying it has a speed improvement for web apps, and that is worth it because indexing isn't important? (Indexing on my web app works just as non-ajax websites, anyway..)

Comment: I guess I'm saying that AJAX works really well, but it can be hard, and one of the hard things is ensuring things get indexed properly. If you don't need it to be indexed (e.g. a webmail client), then that's one less problem to face.

Comment: Why is indexing a problem? If Google visits my web app, it will simply traverse the website without AJAX, and everything works. But if you think it's working really well, and I don't see any problems with implementing it, I'll go for it! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Just that if your site only works with AJAX, then Google might not be able to index it, also if there aren't any URLs - some pages just run everything from the root domain, so there is only one URL with all content – that's not a great idea for indexing.